# Show that the two definitions of LCM are equivalent.

Tags: number-theory, definition, gcd-and-lcm

We can define LCM in two ways:

Defn$1$:   Let $a,b\in \mathbb N$ not both zero and $l\in \mathbb N$ is such that $a\mid l, b\mid l$ and if $a\mid c, b\mid c$ then $l\mid c$. Then $l$ is called the LCM of $a$ and $b$.

Defn$2$: Let $S_{a,b}=\{n\in\mathbb N: a\mid n, b\mid n\}$, $S_{a,b}\neq\varnothing$. By WOP $S_{a,b}$ has a least element $l'$, which is called the LCM of $a$ and $b$.

I want to show that these definitions are equivalent. But I am stuck with the proof. Can someone help?

Comment: Could you do def 2 $\implies$ def 1? That part is easy. If not, please add what you have tried. Or else, I can't post the answer I have.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar I guess the hint lies in the first definition itself

Comment: @SayanDutta I guess my answer is okay?

Comment: @Spectre oh yes, it's quite fine (+1). It wasn't a hard question to be honest. Only that it wasn't (and still isn't) framed "according to the rules", and I'm tired of loosing earned reputation everyday because of deleted questions.

Comment: @SayanDutta oh thanks a lot! At least there's a fellow Indian who can help me work well at number theory.. but to be frank, now that you've pointed out that it's not according to the rules, I may draw enough downvotes ? :D Nvm..

Comment: @SayanDutta Oh sorry.. I thought you were talking about the answer... to be honest I was in a hurry and overread your comment ':)

Comment: @Spectre oh it's fine :) What happens is people delete the whole question (if it's not "according to the rules") and your answer goes away with it too.

Comment: @SayanDutta yeah that's right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I guess here's how it should proceed.

From Defn 2, you can surely see that $l'\mid n \forall n \in S_{a,b}$ and $\min(S_{a,b}) = l$. Also notice that $(a \mid n)\land(b \mid n)\forall n \in S_{a,b}$ with $l'$ being the least. From the first statement, it's obvious that $\exists c : l' \mid c$ and hence $a\mid c, b \mid c$. Also, $a \mid l' , b \mid l'$ which simply satisfies the first definition (I'm not sure if this is all right).

If it's from Defn 1 (as Sayan Dutta doubts in the second part of his comment), I guess here's how it should go: Let $S = \lbrace c : l \mid c, c \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$. By WOP, $\exists k: \min(S) = k$ and it's obvious that $k = l$ since $l \mid l$. Also, since $a \mid l$ and $b \mid l$,$(a \mid n)\land(b \mid n)\forall n \in S $ with $l$  being the least. Thus we see that every element in $S$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$ with $l$ being the least possible number of such a kind, hence we conclude $l = lcm(a,b)$.

I am a grade 11 student and a few chapters that deal with this sort of proof-writing has been deleted from the syllabus temporarily, and hence I'm not so good at proof-writing. It would be worth waiting for a while till a proper answer comes.

Comment: Why is it so that $l'|n$?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar I suggest that you read through the full sentence. I guess I must have confused you but I needed to save time ':). Btw it's mentioned on the same line that $n \in S$

Comment: @KishalaySarkar sorry for the late reply.. I had put myself into replying to Sayan Dutta before actually noticing your message :D